# How to send json Data using RestSharp POST Method in c#

Tags: c#, angular, restsharp

im going to test REST API using RestSharp and required post method to post data and base on callback give status (error,invalid,success) im geting INVALID that is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" [getting json data from header see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaB46.png)

this is my TestMethod

```
     [TestMethod()]
            public void AddNewBFormat()
            {
            Random r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            var x = r.Next(100000, 999999);
            string s = x.ToString("000000");

            string UniqueFileName = "S" + s + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xlsx";
            request.Resource = "api/BFormat/AddNewBFormat";
            request.Method = Method.POST;
            var body= "{'UploadFileVM':{'BordereauxId':null,'BFormatId':null,'FileName':'"+UniqueFileName+ "','Filesize':0,'Path':'C:\\Applications\\new\\\\TempUploadedFiles','size':0,'ActiveSheetIndex':0,'HeaderIndex':0,'MultiHeaders':null,'SheetNames':null,'IsPasswordProtected':false},'BFormat':{'UniqueFileName':'"+ UniqueFileName+"'}}";
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("Application/Json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            var queryResult = client.Execute<ResponseData<Guid>> (request).Data;
            try
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(queryResult.ReturnData != null);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
            }
            }
```

i have tried `request.addJsonBody` also but same result i want to know to send json data using POST Method

Comment: Is your backend able to handle those null-values for BordereauxId & BFormatId?

Comment: yes..in request header null value is going it is work on live site but getting error during test..am i right to send json data using post method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your web api you need to handle the binding json data. WebApi does it by itself normally.
And also you dont have to add header or any parameter with "application/json".
If you could just simply use `AddJsonBody(object obj)` method RestSharp will automatically set the header.

Or another way to do that is:

```
    Random r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    var x = r.Next(100000, 999999);
    string s = x.ToString("000000");
    string UniqueFileName = "S" + s + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xlsx";
    request.Resource = "api/BFormat/AddNewBFormat";
    request.Method = Method.POST;
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    var body = new
    {
        UploadFileVM = new
        {
            BordereauxId = "",
            BFormatId = "",
            FileName = UniqueFileName,
            Filesize = 0,
            Path = @"c:\sdakdldas\"
        }
    };
    request.AddBody(body); //enter code herE
    var queryResult = client.Execute<ResponseData<Guid>>(request).Data;
    try
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(queryResult.ReturnData != null);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
    }
```

And don't serialize the data by urself. RestSharp will take care of serializing.

Comment: thanks..but now problem is how to debug API Server side while test in same project

Comment: required by client